# Drupal install failed due to php version

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have two php version's(5.5.6 and 7). How can i make php 7 version as a default one. when I create a php info file it display's the php version as 5.5.6. But i need php 7 to install Drupal 8

Comment: Your question doesn't look like related to programming directly, so please consider using another site for this.

Comment: Read documentation before asking on stackoverflow : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install & http://kizu514.com/blog/install-php7-and-composer-on-windows-10/